# Missing module links in Python using help()

Tags: python, intellij-idea, module, anaconda

I am using IntelliJ 2016.1. I am taking a Udemy course for Python. In one of the courses, we are calling the help() module. In the lecture, we run help(webbrowser). When the code is run, the output comes up, but without a module link. Yet in the lecture, the module link to that Python.org module is there.

I have Python 3.5.1 and Anaconda 3 installed. I have tried setting both to the default interpreter but no module link.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: what do you mean the output comes up? Like it doesn't give an error when you pass it `help(webbrowser)`?

Comment: Can you provide condensed code examples for the scenario you're describing.

Comment: Luis: The Name and Classes output show up just fine, just no hyperlink to the relevant Python.org section.

Comment: Harmelodic: just open IntelliJ, create a Python file and put help(webbrowser) in the file. Then run it. In the console output you will see all you expect to see except the URL.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
help('webbrowser')
```

last line of output is local link to `webbrowser` module

Comment: Hpure: The last line in the console output is a local link yes. I want the URL so I can click on it and look at all that module has to offer.